# Помогите написать многотабличный запрос

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста с запросом в БД!

Есть три таблицы с полями:

```
1. BATTR:
attach_id
user_id
thd (значение в поле 1 или 0 )

2. BTTTT
topic _id
user_id
cpl (значение в поле 1 или 0 )

3. BTTTS
topic _id
attach_id
```

Нужно составить запрос так чтоб по `user_id` посчитало `cpl=1` и по полученному результату посчитало сколько совпадений по `attach_id` между `thd=1` и `cpl=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял все правильно, можно попробовать отталкиваться от следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  COUNT(R.attach_id)
FROM
  BATTR AS R
JOIN
  BTTTT AS T
USING(user_id)
JOIN
  BTTTS AS S
ON
  S.topic _id = T.topic _id AND
  S.attach_id = R.attach_id
WHERE
  T.cpl = 1 AND
  R.thd = 1
```

Comment: Вокруг да около ходил. Спасибо, работат как надо.